# HTML not showing on webView inside Android

Tags: react-native, webview, android-webview, react-native-webview

I am using **react-native-webview**(https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md) to show some *html* inside both **android** and **ios** devices.

Webview is showing all *htmls* correctly on **iOS** but on **android** there are some *htmls* which aren't displaying consistently. Below is one example which doesn't display on android but does display on iOS.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>;</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2 dir="auto"><strong style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0); background-color: transparent;" dir="auto">What to See and What to Do In London&nbsp;</strong></h2>
      <p dir="auto" style="line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;" dir="auto">We visited England on such countless events and we love its capital city given the sheer number of marvelous activities in London. During our heartfelt 4 days in London schedule, we invested such a lot of energy simply absorbing what the city brings to the table. London implies a great deal to us too, as this is the city where we requested our wedding bands from. It's likewise the very first city we had a movement date in, with a cool visit around Tate Modern. We are sure you will go gaga for London and will need to return for additional. Also, assuming you visit London with your family, have confidence there are a lot of free London exhibition halls for youngsters too.</span></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

My code:

```
const {html} = props
    const newHtml = `<h2 dir="auto"><strong style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0); background-color: transparent;" dir="auto">What to See and What to Do In London&nbsp;</strong></h2><p dir='auto' style='line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;'><span style='font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;' dir='auto'>We visited England on such countless events and we love its capital city given the sheer number of marvelous activities in London. During our heartfelt 4 days in London schedule, we invested such a lot of energy simply absorbing what the city brings to the table. London implies a great deal to us too, as this is the city where we requested our wedding bands from. It's likewise the very first city we had a movement date in, with a cool visit around Tate Modern. We are sure you will go gaga for London and will need to return for additional. Also, assuming you visit London with your family, have confidence there are a lot of free London exhibition halls for youngsters too.</span></p>`
    const htmlStr = '<\!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>;</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body>' + html.toString() + '</body></html>'
    const webiewStyle = {...styles.webView, minHeight: (html.length)}
    console.log('htmlStr', htmlStr)
    const [webViewHeight, setWebViewHeight] = useState((html.length))
    const webViewStyle = useMemo(() => ({height: webViewHeight}), [webViewHeight])
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <WebView
                style={[webiewStyle, webViewStyle]}
                source={{html: htmlStr, baseUrl: ''}}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}
                androidLayerType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'hardware' : ''}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                onMessage={event => { setWebViewHeight(parseInt(event.nativeEvent.data)+10)}}
                injectedJavaScript='window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)'
                // useWebKit={true}
                viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0'}
                onContentProcessDidTerminate={(syntheticEvent) => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
                    console.log('Content process terminated, reloading', nativeEvent)
                    this.refs.webview.reload()
                }}
                onError={(syntheticEvent) => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
                    console.log('WebView error: ', nativeEvent)
                }}
                mixedContentMode={'always'}
                onRenderProcessGone={() => alert('ahooo')}
                overScrollMode={'never'}
            />
        
        </View>
    )
```

Below is **HTML** which works fine for both **android** and **ios** devices.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>;</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p dir="auto" style="line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-style: normal; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal;" dir="auto">Thinking about what are the best activities in London? Home to 4 world legacy locales, established by the Romans and the present one of the main monetary center points on the planet, London is an assorted city, known for its craft, culture, religions, and trendy personal areas. London is one of the world's greenest urban communities, home to the notorious Big Ben and the Royal Family. London is a dynamic city, brimming with promising circumstances and probably the coolest spot in Europe. Britain's capital is a flat-out must-see.</span></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. So I used below props for WebView on android. I had to use **androidLayerType={'hardware'}** but it introduced crashing issue for android navigation. So I used **androidLayerType={'hardware'}** and **opacity: 0.99** in styles.
For more detail check below code.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {justifyContent: 'center', marginBottom: 10, opacity: 0.99, overflow: 'hidden' , width: '100%'},
    webView: { height: 'auto', marginBottom: 20, marginTop: 20, opacity: 0.99, overflow: 'hidden', width: Metrics.screenWidth - 50 }
})

const HTMLView = props => {
    const {html} = props
    // const newHtml = `<h2 dir="auto"><strong style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0); background-color: transparent;" dir="auto">What to See and What to Do In London&nbsp;</strong></h2><p dir='auto' style='line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;'><span style='font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;' dir='auto'>We visited England on such countless events and we love its capital city given the sheer number of marvelous activities in London. During our heartfelt 4 days in London schedule, we invested such a lot of energy simply absorbing what the city brings to the table. London implies a great deal to us too, as this is the city where we requested our wedding bands from. It's likewise the very first city we had a movement date in, with a cool visit around Tate Modern. We are sure you will go gaga for London and will need to return for additional. Also, assuming you visit London with your family, have confidence there are a lot of free London exhibition halls for youngsters too.</span></p>`
    const htmlStr = '<\!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>&nbsp;</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body>' + html.toString() + '</body></html>'
    const webiewStyle = {...styles.webView, minHeight: (html.length)}

    const [webViewHeight, setWebViewHeight] = useState((html.length))
    const webViewStyle = useMemo(() => ({height: webViewHeight}), [webViewHeight])
    // const webViewStyle = {height: webViewHeight}

    return (
        <View
            style={styles.container}
        >
            {Platform.OS === 'ios' ? <WebView
                style={[webiewStyle, webViewStyle]}
                source={{html: htmlStr, baseUrl: ''}}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                onMessage={event => { setWebViewHeight(parseInt(event.nativeEvent.data)+10)}}
                injectedJavaScript='window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)'
                // useWebKit={true}
                viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0'}
                onContentProcessDidTerminate={(syntheticEvent) => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
                    console.log('Content process terminated, reloading', nativeEvent)
                    this.refs.webview.reload()
                }}
                onError={(syntheticEvent) => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
                    console.log('WebView error: ', nativeEvent)
                }}
            /> : <WebView
                style={[webiewStyle, webViewStyle]}
                source={{html: htmlStr, baseUrl: ''}}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                nestedScrollEnabled={false}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={false}
                androidLayerType={'hardware'}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                onMessage={event => { setWebViewHeight(parseInt(event.nativeEvent.data)+10)}}
                injectedJavaScript='window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)'
                useWebKit={true}
                viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0'}
                onContentProcessDidTerminate={(syntheticEvent) => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
                    console.log('Content process terminated, reloading', nativeEvent)
                    this.refs.webview.reload()
                }}
                onError={(syntheticEvent) => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
                    console.log('WebView error: ', nativeEvent)
                }}
                mixedContentMode={'always'}
                overScrollMode={'never'}
            />}
        </View>
    )
}
```

I am using both **androidLayerType={'hardware'}** and **androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={false}** here. (Although some solutions suggested otherwise.)

I was also facing the crash issue due to'react-native-youtube-iframe' and to fix this I used **opacity: 0.99** for **webViewStyle** prop in this component.

I also applied opacity:0.99 for all webviews I was showing inside the list of item.